# What kind of query do I need?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called physical_exam_tool_and_body_parts that has:

```
id physical_exam_tool_id body_part_id
```

the body_parts table has: `name_tid`

the physical_exam_tools table has: `name_tid`

The translation table looks like:

```
id lang text
```

I'm trying to query:

```
SELECT physical_exam_tool_text,
       body_part_text
FROM   physical_exam_tool_and_body_parts
WHERE  translation.lang = 'fr'
```

I want the names of the body part and physical exam tool for the lang 'fr'. How can I do this. I'm new to joins.

body_parts and physical_exam_tools tables have:

```
id name_tid
```

name_tid is the id in the translation table. The translation table has id lang text. So the primary key for translations is a composite key (id,lang).

In physical_exam_body_part_and_tool the id's in that are just the ids (foreign keys) for the body_parts and physical_exam_tools table.

Comment: Look for `Inner Join`. `select ... from physical_exam_tool_and_body_parts A inner join translation b on a.id = b.id where b.lang = 'fr'`

Comment: @Fireblade it is a little more complex than that. body_part_id is only a link to the body_parts table and the body_parts table has the name_tid which is the id for the translations table.

Comment: Can you clarify your table structure please

Comment: `physical_exam_tool_and_body_parts` sounds like a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) for a many-to-many relationship, but I don't understand how `translation` is related at all.  It usually helps to post some sample data from each table and what you want the results to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to the Translation Table twice where lang = 'fr'.

```
SELECT t.[text] AS [ExamTool], t2.[text] AS [BodyPart] 
FROM   physical_exam_tool_and_body_parts as p
    inner join physical_exam_tool as pet
    on p.physical_exam_tool_id = pet.physical_exam_tool_id
    and t.lang = 'fr'
        inner join translation as t
        on pet.name_tid = t.id
    inner join body_parts as b
    on p.body_part_id = b.body_part_id
        inner join translation as t2
        on b.name_tid = t2.id
        and t2.lang = 'fr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
SELECT PHYSICAL_EXAM_TOOL_TEXT,
       BODY_PART_TEXT
FROM   PHYSICAL_EXAM_TOOL_AND_BODY_PARTS A
       INNER JOIN BODY_PARTS B
               ON A.BODY_PART_ID = B.ID
       INNER JOIN TRANSLATION C
               ON C.ID = B.NAME_TID
WHERE  C.LANG = 'FR'
```